# Customizing Trac: remove standard footer

Tags: trac, genshi

We use hosted Trac. 
It uses Genshi templates.
I think we can submit our own site.html.
We want to get rid of Trac standard footer.
What is the most elegant way of doing that?

I suspect that the answer is in some nice Genshi trick.
I don't know Genshi nor Trac's additions to it.
I tried couple of things on a hunch, none worked.

I tried css

```
 <style type="text/css">
     #footer 
     {
         visibility:hidden;
     }
 </style>
```

That is ok, unless you want to use your own footer (called "#sitefooter"). 
This one comes after "#footer", and hiding footer leaves an ugly white space.

Then I tried jquery:

```
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) { $("#footer").text(''); });
</script>
```

This is fine yet I am not sure how wide support for jquery really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a recent copy of trac on me at present to poke into as far as templates go, but for CSS, you want to try

```
display: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

instead of

```
visibility:hidden;
```

visibility hidden items still take up space.

Comment: margin and padding are probably superfluous.

Comment: css seems a more standard way of not displaying something then DOM manipulation in javascript. I still regret not being able to do it on the server side with some Genshi magic.

Comment: Better to use Marcin's updated method below as it is the official Trac manner of overriding site elements.

Answer (score 2):

The most elegant way is to just change it in trac.ini.
The footer is set in in trac.ini, and this is the default:

```
[project]
footer = Visit the Trac open source project at<br /><a href="http://trac.edgewall.org/">http://trac.edgewall.org/</a>
```

Comment: This does not eleminate the whole of the footer, just the text line on the right hand side of the footer.

Comment: right, sorry for incorrect answer,
to remove the footer completely you can add this to site.html (I tested it on ver. 0.12 from svn):

    <div py:match="div[@id='footer']"></div>

Answer (score 2):

Most elegant way is to modify site.html under

```
/path-to-trac/projectname/templates/
```

Example site.html file:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/" py:strip="">
<!--! Custom match templates go here -->
<div py:match="div[@id='footer']">
    <!-- put custom footer markup here -->
</div>
</html>
```

Credit to marcin.

Comment: you should include the id="footer" in the code above if you want to keep formatting but change values, like adding visitor tracking.

<div py:match="div[@id='footer']" id="footer">